# How can I pass a variable number of named parameters to a method?

Tags: c#, .net

I understand how to get the names of parameters passed to a method, but let's say I have a method declaration as follows:

```
static void ParamsTest(string template, params object[] objects)
```

and I want to use object/property names in my template for substitution with real property values in any of the objects in my `objects' parameter.  Let's then say I call this method with:

```
ParamsTest("Congrats", customer, purchase);
```

I will only be able to retrieve two parameter names trying to fill out the template, viz, `template`, and `objects`, and the names of the objects in the `objects` collection are forever lost, or not?

I could require a `List<object>` as my second parameter, but I feel there is somehow a more elegant solution, maybe with a lambda or something.  I don't know, I'm not used to using lambdas outside of LINQ.

Comment: What about a `Dictionary<string,object>`, where the string is the name of the variable?

Comment: +1. can somehow use C#4's actual named params? `ParamTest(customer: customer, purchase:purchase)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inpsired by Mark I can offer an anonymous type answer :

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParamsTest(new { A = "a", B = "b"});
        }

        public static void ParamsTest(object o)
        {
            if (o == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }
            var t = o.GetType();
            var aValue = t.GetProperty("A").GetValue(o, null);
            var bValue = t.GetProperty("B").GetValue(o, null);
        }
    }
}
```

However this DOES have drawbacks :

- No type safety. I can pass in any object
- I can pass in an anonymous type with different members and/or types than those expected
- You should also do more checking than in this short sample

Comment: You can also reorder parameters in the call :)

Comment: I wish I could vote Mark up as well, but his is not an answer.  Thanks, this is my chosen route.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a parameters object :

```
public class ParamsTestParams {
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }

    public static readonly ParamsTestParams Empty = new ParamsTestParams();
}
```

Change the methods signature to :

```
ParamsTest(ParamsTestParams parameters)
```

And call your method like so :

```
ParamsTest(new ParamsTestParams { A = "abc" });
```

or :

```
ParamsTest(new ParamsTestParams { B = "abc" });
```

or :

```
ParamsTest(new ParamsTestParams { A = "abc", B = "xyz" });
```

or :

```
ParamsTest(ParamsTestParams.Empty); // instead of null so you don't have to do null checks in the method's body
```

and so on.

Comment: could use an anonymous object instead in c#4

Comment: yes, but obtaining its members and their names inside ParamsTest is not a simple task - it involves reflection

Comment: Or I could just use a Dictionary<string, object> :-)

Comment: You can also reorder parameters in the call :)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just do it like this:

```
static void ParamsTest(string template, object[] objects)
```

and call it like this:

```
ParamsTest("Congrats", new object[] { customer, purchase });
```

Comment: Just as in my anonymous type sample, you don't really have type safety, also you don't have parameter naming.

Also, you can be shorter in syntax from "new object[] { ... }" to "new [] { ... }"

Comment: I really, really need parameter naming.

Comment: Then I think Oded's suggestion of Dictionary<string,object> is your easiest option